# Rewrite part of a URL to capitals

Tags: codeigniter, iis

I have a CodeIgniter application that I'm maintaining and all internal links follow a structure like:

website.com/name-of-application/page

However, the page is only served if the middle section follows a specific capitalization structure:

(ie: website.com/Name-Of-application/page)

This is strange to me, because all of the files themselves are lowercased. Is there an easy way to redirect/rewrite URLs to follow the strange casing in either IIS or CodeIgniter itself? Thanks so much

Comment: what is the CI version, any "strange" routing in config/routes.php? how does the .htacess look like? show a little bit of the codes related to that! thanks

Comment: Issue was an IIS rewrite rule was applying where it shouldn't have been. Just disabled and restarted and the page started serving correctly with all lower URL